# Button does not work in second (nested) figure

Tags: python, button, matplotlib, fedora

I think I've come across a bug in Matplotlib, though I really hope it's just something simple I'm missing.

The code I'm working on has worked well on Ubuntu 11.10, Ubuntu 12.04, and MacOS. Recently I installed Fedora 18 on my machine and I've noticed Matplotlib is having some issues: I have a figure with a button. Click the button, it opens another window which also has some buttons. The buttons in the second window are inactive on my Fedora system. They don't respond to hover (they don't change color), and they don't respond to click.

Here's a small piece of code that simulates this issue. This works well on my Ubuntu 12.04, but not on Fedora. It's supposed to work as follows: show a figure with a big button, if you click the button it will show another figure which in turn has button too. If all is well, the second button should respond to hover and print something to the terminal when clicked.

```
import pylab
from matplotlib.widgets import Button


def draw_button1(event):

    pylab.figure()
    a = pylab.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
    b = Button(a, 'Button 1')

    def say_something(event):
        print "This works."

    b.on_clicked(say_something)
    pylab.show()

def draw_button2():
    pylab.figure()
    a = pylab.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
    b = Button(a, 'Button 2')
    b.on_clicked(draw_button1)
    pylab.show()

draw_button2()
```

I have no idea what is causing this. I've tried a number of things:

1. I've installed Matplitlib 1.2.0, 1.2.1 from yum repository, and the latest 1.3.0rc2 which I built from source. They all do the same. I've also installed all relevant dependencies of Matplotlib, even those optional.
2. I've tried to run my piece of code remotely on Ubuntu 12.04 from my Fedora machine.. Maybe there's a problem with how X renders those windows? Still works on my Ubuntu, rendering on my Fedora.
3. Furious googling on this issue which hasn't really helped. People suggest using  `pylab.ion()` and `pylab.ioff()` for interactive plots, but that hasn't helped either.

If it helps in any way, here's my Matplotlib build:

```
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.3.0rc2]
                python: yes [2.7.3 (default, Aug  9 2012, 17:23:57)  [GCC
                        4.7.1 20120720 (Red Hat 4.7.1-5)]]
              platform: yes [linux2]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.7.1]
              dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 1.5]
               tornado: yes [using tornado version 3.1]
             pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 1.5.6]
                 pycxx: yes [Couldn't import.  Using local copy.]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: yes [version 15.0.9]
                   png: yes [version 1.5.13]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
                 tests: yes [using nose version 1.3.0]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                qt4agg: no  [PyQt4 not found]
               gtk3agg: yes [version 3.4.6]
             gtk3cairo: yes [version 3.4.6]
                gtkagg: yes [Gtk: 2.24.18 pygtk: 2.24.0]
                 tkagg: no  [The C/C++ header for Tk (tk.h) could not be
                        found.  You may need to install the development
                        package.]
                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                   gtk: yes [Gtk: 2.24.18 pygtk: 2.24.0]
                   agg: yes [installing]
                 cairo: yes [version 1.8.10]
             windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: yes [version 1.14]
           ghostscript: yes [version 9.06]
                 latex: no
               pdftops: yes [version 0.20.2]
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into issues of scoping.  When the button object goes out of scope all the call backs on it are cleaned up.  For your buttons to work, you need to keep a reference to the `Button` object around.

```
def draw_button2():
    pylab.figure()
    a = pylab.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
    b = Button(a, 'Button 2')
    b.on_clicked(draw_button1)
    pylab.show()
    return b

b = draw_button2()
```

This will make your *first* button work, but to get the second one working, you will need some sort of global structure.   The elegent way to do this is to wrap all of these functions up in a class to keep track of them, the hacky way to do this is to add attributes to the figure objects:

```
import pylab
from matplotlib.widgets import Button


def draw_button1(event):
    fig = pylab.figure()
    a = pylab.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
    b = Button(a, 'Button 1')

    def say_something(event):
        print "This works."

    b.on_clicked(say_something)
    fig._my_btn = b
    pylab.show()

def draw_button2():
    fig = pylab.figure()
    a = pylab.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
    b = Button(a, 'Button 2')
    b.on_clicked(draw_button1)
    pylab.show()
    fig._my_btn = b


draw_button2()
```

Comment: Thank you! This indeed fixed it! So really it should have not worked well on my other systems either...

Comment: And once again, whenever I thought I found a bug in some library it turned out to by fault. :)

Comment: @Diana Did you read the button example? (http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/buttons.html) If so, I will submit a PR to make it clear that this is important.  As for why it worked anywhere, there were some changes is the way call backs worked awhile ago (changed -> weakrefs), but I am not sure where that ended up in the released versions.

Comment: Yes, I wrote my code based on that example about six months ago. This time around though, I was really looking for the problem everywhere else but this. It worked on my other systems, so I assumed I'm very likely doing it right, and the issue is somewhere with Matplotlib. Thanks very much for your tips!